# How do you pass a custom parameter in Twilio with PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Taking a look from here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/twiml
The closest I could get was this:

```
$response = new Twiml();
$callerIdNumber = config('services.twilio')['number'];
$dial = $response->dial(['callerId' => $callerIdNumber]);
$dial->parameter([
     "name" => "firstname",
     "value" => "Test Firstname",
]);

$dial->parameter([
    "name" => "lastname",
    "value" => "Test lastname",
]);

$dial->client('support_agent');
return $response;
```

but it throws an invalid XML warning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+12055461045">
        <Parameter name="firstname" value="Test Firstname"/>
        <Parameter name="lastname" value="Test lastname"/>
        <Client>support_agent</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

In the docs, it's supposed to look like this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>
            <Identity>joey</Identity>
            <Parameter name="firstname" value="Test Firstname"/>
            <Parameter name="lastname" value="Test lastname"/>
        </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I've tried so many things but they all throw an application error. Here are two that I've tried. The other stuff I've tried I've already forgotten.

```
// trial 1
$dial->client->identity('support_agent')
$dial->client->parameter([
    "name" => "firstname",
    "value" => "Test Firstname",
]);

//trial 2
$dial->client->identity('support_agent', array('parameter' => [
    "name" => "firstname",
    "value" => "Test Firstname",
]))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hope this will help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430270/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-custom-parameter-when-make-a-call-with-twilio/35318869

Comment: Hi @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie, thanks. I've passed that but it's a bit outdated since it's from 2015. The docs show that TwiML has a capability to pass custom parameters but doesn't state how in php.

Comment: @JRRequiroso I think you have to pass this parameter related code  in the new created variable of client function related code. Let me check this thing at my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the below PHP code sample to add the custom parameter and this code is tested by me at on local system now.

```
        require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
        use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

        $response = new VoiceResponse();
        $dial = $response->dial('');
        $client = $dial->client();
        $identity = $client->Identity('user-jane');

        $client->parameter([
             "name" => "firstname",
             "value" => "Test Firstname",
        ]);

        $client->parameter([
            "name" => "lastname",
            "value" => "Test lastname",
        ]);

        echo $response;
```

> Response is below

```
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Client>
        <Identity>user-jane</Identity>
        <Parameter name="firstname" value="Test Firstname" />
        <Parameter name="lastname" value="Test lastname" />
    </Client>
</Dial>
```

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that?! Thank you so much! This is great!

Comment: I have just thought about how the child-parent structure of XML can be created by PHP function. Anyway, if your issue is solved then you can tick as a right answer.